# how to dynamically render a textbox value in asp.net web page into the same position in a PDF using iTextSharp?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf

How to dynamically render a textbox value in Asp.net web page into PDF using iTextSharp?

The text have to be placed in the PDF in the same position as the textbox in the web page, as the number of textboxes vary in different scenarios because the textboxes are contained in different FormViews. There are many FormViews in the page & only some FormViews will be datbound in some cases. So we cant set a position for each textbox. The position should be same as that in the web page.

I have done like this:

```
        Dim TextBox5 As TextBox = DirectCast(FormView2.FindControl("TextBox5"), TextBox)

        Dim htmlarraylist As List(Of IElement) = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(New StringReader(TextBox5.Text), Nothing)

        For Each element As IElement In htmlarraylist

            document.Add(element)

        Next
```

But the textbox will be added to the last of the PDF document only.

If it is to be placed at an absolute position in PDF, it can be done like this:

```
        Dim cb As PdfContentByte = writer.DirectContent

        cb.BeginText()

        Dim TextBox5 As TextBox = DirectCast(FormView2.FindControl("TextBox5"), TextBox)

        Dim text As String = TextBox5.Text

        cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 8)

        cb.ShowTextAligned(1, text, 122, 474, 0)

        cb.EndText()
```

But both of these cant be done in my case. Please help.

Comment: does anybody know how to do this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had found out a way to tackle this, which I wanted to share.

A dynamic textbox value won't be rendered into a PDF automatically. So an invisible label is added along with the textbox inside the FormView. And in the button click of creating PDF, coded like below:

```
    Dim nametxt As TextBox = DirectCast(FormView2.FindControl("TextBox5"), TextBox)

    Dim namelbl As Label = DirectCast(FormView2.FindControl("Label10"), Label)

    namelbl.Text = nametxt.Text

    namelbl.Visible = True

    nametxt.Visible = False
```

Then that label will automatically be rendered at the same position in the PDF as that in the web page. That's it. Sooo simple logic. :)